# I am not able to successfully run "Pod instal" command

Tags: ios, flutter, mobile

I am encountering an error while running Pod install.  Below is the error I'm getting.

```
Analyzing dependencies
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.15.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '10.15.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
Downloading dependencies
Installing AppsFlyerFramework (6.13.1)

[!] Error installing AppsFlyerFramework
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/l4/yc0f8mkn6lvd2gtmlx09mw_c0000gn/T/d20240316-54206-1lrxjxm/file.zip https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/AppsFlyerFramework/releases/download/6.13.1/AppsFlyerLib-Binaries.zip --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2 -A 'CocoaPods/1.15.2 cocoapods-downloader/2.1'

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:05:03 --:--:--     0
curl: (28) SSL connection timeout
Warning: Problem : timeout. Will retry in 1 seconds. 2 retries left.
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:05:02 --:--:--     0
curl: (28) Send failure: Broken pipe
Warning: Problem : timeout. Will retry in 2 seconds. 1 retries left.
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:05:03 --:--:--     0
curl: (28) Send failure: Broken pipe
```

I have searched online but can't find much related to this.